# NGINX proxy redirect doesn't redirect correctly. 405 Not Allowed

Tags: nginx

I have some old system with strange problem because it is now moved to nginx. I am using signalr behind which support websockets.

I always get **405 Not Allowed**

nginx conf file for redirection and websocket support

```
location /signalr-websocket/ {
    rewrite                  ^/signalr-websocket/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass               https://signalr.domain.com;
    proxy_http_version       1.1;
    proxy_set_header         Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header         Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header         Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass       $http_upgrade;
  }
```

and my url which sould then redirect to correct path is

> https://my.domain.com/signalr-websocket/signalshub/negotiate?userId=undefined&negotiateVersion=1

should then be redirected to

> https://signalr.domain.com/signalshub/negotiate?userId=undefined&negotiateVersion=1

Problem is that is not correctly redirected. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing backslash to `proxy_pass` and getting rid of `rewrite` ?

Comment: Hi. Can you give me an example. I tried a lot but not sure if you mean the same. Thank you.

Comment: I tried but I still get 405 Not Allowed

Comment: For better debugging you can put `rewrite_log on;` in your `server` block but for the best result you should obtain an nginX which was compiled with debugging capabilities (`--with-debug` - you can check with `nginx -V`) and then use `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;` to see what exactly is happening with the redirection. The issue will become obvious.